# I tried to put the files on the same folder but still gives an error when using open()

Tags: python

I'm currently learning python and now I'm trying to open a file with open()

```
text = open("myFile.txt", "r")

print(text.read())

text.close()
```

Even though I put my python file and the .txt file on the same folder it still gives an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reading_files.py", line 1, in <module>
    text = open("myFile.txt")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myFile.txt'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. I have to say, you haven't given nearly enough information to help anyone understand why you get this error. Are you sure the name of the file is correct? Are you sure you have read permissions for that file? How are you executing `reading_files.py`?

Comment: Also, this won't fix your error, but a very good practice in python is to use a `with` environment rather than having to close the file explicitly yourself. See this page of the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Does myFile.txt exist

Comment: It is looking for `myFile.txt` relative to the directory from which you run the python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being totally honest, it's true that there's a lack of information. You might have typed your folder structure or where the file is.

Is it in the directory you are running the script? Then your sintax should work flawlessly unless you are using a an IDE such as VSCode, in that case if you don't open the folder your `.py` and `.txt` are in, it assumes you are `C:\Users\%username%\`. So your code is correct but the directory you are looking for is wrong.

You can avoid this by avoiding relative paths and working with absolute paths such `r'C:\Users\FirstName.LastName\Documents\myFile.txt'`

You can think about the relative path you are using as an 'autocomplete' that looks up in the directory you are running the script in.

Being absolutely  honest with you, I would avoid importing libraries for mundane tasks if you aren't worrying about performances, and this doesn't seem the case at all. So just go with:

```
absolute_path = r'C:\Users\FirstName.LastName\Documents\myFile.txt'
with open(absolute_path, 'r') as file:
    reader = file.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

The file with the relative path, like the one you specified, is searched in the [*current working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), and not in the same directory as where the python script is.

If you want to resolve a relative path with respect to the python script (`__file__`), you can do:

```
import os
fullpath = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'myfile.txt')
)

text = open(fullpath, "r")
...
```

Answer (score -3):

Hi try adding up these lines at the top of you code

```
import sys, os, inspect

currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
filepath = os.path.join(currentdir, 'myFile.txt')
text = open(filepath , "r")
print(text.read())
text.close()
```

Comment: this will get the exact current directory of your code and then join the file name to the dir. giving you a full path so that it can be used to open